# Gutenberg Gallery Block – Same Size Pictures Fix

Tags: css, wordpress, image-gallery, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I just want to share a quick fix for the Gutenberg gallery since I couldn't find the fix anywhere else. What will fix:

- **Problem**: If you upload images to your gallery that have different sizes, the thumbnails are displayed in different heights on each row. **Fix**: All images will have a squared shape.
- **Problem**: When adding 4 photos to a 3 rows Gutenberg Gallery Block, always the 4th picture takes the entire width of the container. **Fix**: Each image will keep the same width.

Gutenberg Gallery Block 4th row image size issue:

[image: gutenberg gallery image 4th row size issue]

Gutenberg Gallery Block same size fix:

[image: gutenberg gallery image 4th row size fix]

Answer (score 4):

Simple CSS Fix:

```
.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images figure.wp-block-image img {
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* squared size thumbnails */ 
}
.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images figure.wp-block-image {
  flex-grow: 0; /* width fix */ 
}
```

Comment: I was struggling with max-width calculations for every n-columns use case. Your solution is much more clever and more simple. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Works great but my thumbnails were distorted. Adding object-fit helped:

`.wp-block-gallery.has-nested-images figure.wp-block-image img {
 aspect-ratio: 1; /* squared size thumbnails */
 object-fit: cover;
}`